# Is it possible to register multiple timeouts in mio?

Tags: rust, mio

I have written a TCP server in mio and registered multiple timeouts, but only the last registered timeout fires. Do I need a wrapper for my timeouts to combine them or are there any other ways to register multiple timeouts in mio v0.5?

Comment: What do you mean with lower?

Comment: why not take the smaller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I registered a tuple with an id

```
event_loop.timeout_ms((id, ServerTimeout::T1(timeout)), duration)
```

It didn't work, so I added `id` to `ServerTimeout::T1` and called the `timeout_ms` method again:

```
event_loop.timeout_ms(ServerTimeout::T1(id, timeout), duration)
```